# Remove line self intersections?

Tags: qgis, line, esri-production-mapping

I have a polyline that is self intersecting in some points and I want to create a "clean" version of it.

Basically something like that [Remove Self Intersections](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/production-mapping-toolbox/remove-self-intersections.htm#) in the first image(single part). So all self intersecting "small" parts are deleted.

[image]

But I do not have a production mapping license. Can this be achieved in QGIS?

Comment: Vanilla ArcGIS can [repair geometries](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm) without Production Mapping.

Comment: I tried but I do not think it works in this case